# How to generate javadoc directly from Git

Tags: java, git, javadoc, fest

I am looking for Fest APIs for Java swing application testing.
I can't seem to find any APIs posted online anywhere (their website seems to be down) and I've decided to check out the Git repository that you can download the source code from to do what you wish with.
But when I do this there are tons of errors and the Java doc refuses to get generated.

I was curious if anyone knew where I could either find a copy of the docs or if it is possible to generate the docs directly from Git?

Comment: It looks like the documentation is attached as part of the POM in its Maven repository.  Further to that, the reason you're likely having errors is that your environment isn't configured to use the m2 repository as a resource, or you don't have enough of the dependencies properly configured on your box.

Comment: @Makoto How exactly could I go about getting/seeing a copy of the doc?

Comment: Either look at it in the Maven repository it's uploaded to, or run `mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc` from the command line.

Comment: @Makoto I was able to locate the Maven repository at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.easytesting/fest-assert for the assert jar in fest.   I am new to Maven repositories and I can't find anything that resembles documentation of any kind.  Am I looking in the wrong place or am I making noob mistakes and simply looking over what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [fest-assert-2.x issue 167](https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-assert-2.x/issues/167):

Fest Assert is not active anymore these days, you might have a look to [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/index.html) a fork of [fest-assert-2.x](https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-assert-2.x).
... And yes, that fork AssertJ does have a JavaDoc API!

http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/index.html

The [latest release](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-news.html#assertj-core-3.8.0) dates from 10 days ago: [AssertJ Core 2.8.0](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-news.html#assertj-core-2.8.0) 2017-05-21.